# Установка Laravel на mac os XAMPP

Tags: laravel, macos, установка, xampp

Привет всем!

Проблема с открытием проекта через localhost при установке laravel 5.1 версии.

Моя последовательность действий:

- Устанавливаю Laravel на OS X 10.11.6 с помощью composser с XAMPP
- Создал проект в папке /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/laravel/
- В файле host из папки /etc прописал 127.0.0.1 guestbook.local
- Теперь по моему мануалу надо поменять в файле httpd-vhosts.conf следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том что на компьютере нашлось много таких файлов (httpd-vhosts.conf) я попробовал во всех включить этот текст - не сработало, по адресу guestbook.local открывает вот такую заглушку вместо моего проекта

Где я ошибся при настройке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

Скажу честно, если у тебя мас ставь [Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/valet) и не ломай мозг. Ну а еще мне кажется у тебя опечатка publuc вместо public :)

Answer (score -1):

1. В командной строке можешь набирать `php artisan serve` и никакой xampp, valet не нужен.
2. Или же можешь установить php7 из macports ([туториал на английском](https://tech.enekochan.com/en/2015/12/05/install-php7-in-mac-os-x-with-macports/)).

или же как сказал @Orange_shadow, у тебя опечатка **publuc** вместо **public**

Answer (score -1):

Если речь о XAMPP и macOS, получается сперва нужно проверить файл `httpd.conf`, полный путь:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf
```

Там раскомментировать строчку

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /Applications/XAMPP/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Затем уже перейти к настройке `VirtualHost` в файле `httpd-vhosts.conf` по адресу что указан в файле `httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName guestbook.local
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/laravel/guestbook/public"
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

И настройки хостов на маке, открываешь, как тебе удобно, файл`/etc/hosts` и добавляешь строчку

```
127.0.0.1 guestbook.local
```